# Get the mode name of any buffer in Emacs

Tags: emacs

How can I get information about what mode a certain buffer is in in emacs. For example when I'm in buffer x how can i find ut if it is actually view-mode or whatever else it might be. The reason I want this is so that I can customize evil mode to only the buffers where I want it using:

```
(add-to-list 'evil-insert-state-modes 'view-mode)
```

The problem is that I don't know what the names are of the actual different modes I want to add to this list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hit <kbd>M-:</kbd> and type `major-mode`.  You'll see the name of the major mode of the current buffer in the echo area.

Comment: Nice, now evil starts to make more sense!

Comment: Or just use `C-h v major-mode`, which gives you completion. (This shows you not just the value but what the variable `major-mode` is for.)